# How to intercept a flash game's network traffic that doesn't show up in chrome's developer tools

Tags: python, sniffing, google-chrome-devtools, network-traffic

Go to fairgocasino.com in chrome and open any game (let's take for example the first slot in alphabetical order, "5 Wishes").  Open the network tab of developer tools with rightclick -> Inspect -> Network.  Then play the game with the play money balance.  Nothing new shows up in the network tab.  So flash is somehow communicating directly with the server, without going through the browser.

If chrome devtools won't work here, what else can I use to programmatically observe that traffic (preferably at higher level of abstraction than packet sniffing, because I want to see the whole contents of the response, and preferably in python)?

Comment: Also packet sniffing wouldn't even work if the underlying communication is over HTTPS like everything else on that site.

I'm 100% certain all slot games operate by sending a separate request to the server each time you spin and receiving a response that says the number of credits won, the orientation of the reels, etc.  My goal is to record the latter.

Comment: perhaps you can look into using burpsuite as an intercepting proxy?

Comment: Flash ignores browser proxy settings, so that won't work